# Is it possible to share internet connection with mobile phone from a PC

Tags: ad-hoc-network

I am connected to my PC by cable (No WI-FI), I would like to know id it is possible to share this connection (connect my mobile phone) to internet without using cable connection with PC ?

Comment: Yes, search for "windows wireless ad-hoc network" (assuming you are using windows.

Comment: I have already tried it but the phone does not detect the network !!!